# How to make Rails.logger.debug print hash more readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging, pretty-print

I'm using Rails.logger.debug print variables for debugging purposes.  The issue is it prints hashes in an impossible to read format (can't distinguish keys from values).  For example, I add the following lines to my code base

```
#code_base.rb
 my_hash = {'a' => 'alligator', 'b'=>'baboon'}
 Rails.logger.debug my_hash
```

Then I launch my rails app and type

```
  tail -f log/development.log
```

But when my_hash gets printed, it looks like

```
  bbaboonaalligator
```

The key and values are scrunched up, making it impossible to parse.  Do you guys know what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer to my own question.  I need to use

```
my_hash = {'a' => 'alligator', 'b'=>'baboon'}
Rails.logger.debug "#{my_hash.inspect}"
```

Then, it looks like

```
{"b"=>"baboon", "a"=>"aligator"}
```

Answer (score 16):

It's even easier to read it when you use `to_yaml` eg:

`logger.debug my_hash.to_yaml`

Which is an easy to read format over multiple lines. The `inspect` method simply spews out a string.

Comment: Great tip here! `to_yaml` also creates a string, but it's formatted with `\n` and indentation so it's much easier to skim a large or nested hash… If you're trying to log a hash-like object (say, `params`), you may end up with `ivars` clogging the data you're interested in. Turn it into a normal hash first and then turn that into yaml: `logger.debug params.to_hash.to_yaml`

Answer (score 3):

```
my_hash = {'a' => 'alligator', 'b'=>'baboon'}
logger.debug "#{my_hash}"
```

Then, it looks like

```
{"b"=>"baboon", "a"=>"aligator"}
```

do not need **inspect**

Answer (score 1):

There is an another way to do this. There is a ruby built in module [pp.rb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) that is Pretty-printer for Ruby objects.

non-pretty-printed output by p is:

```
#<PP:0x81fedf0 @genspace=#<Proc:0x81feda0>, @group_queue=#<PrettyPrint::GroupQueue:0x81fed3c @queue=[[#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @breakables=[], @depth=0, @break=false>], []]>, @buffer=[], @newline="\n", @group_stack=[#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @breakables=[], @depth=0, @break=false>], @buffer_width=0, @indent=0, @maxwidth=79, @output_width=2, @output=#<IO:0x8114ee4>>
```

pretty-printed output by pp is:

```
#<PP:0x81fedf0
 @buffer=[],
 @buffer_width=0,
 @genspace=#<Proc:0x81feda0>,
 @group_queue=
  #<PrettyPrint::GroupQueue:0x81fed3c
   @queue=
    [[#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @break=false, @breakables=[], @depth=0>],
     []]>,
 @group_stack=
  [#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @break=false, @breakables=[], @depth=0>],
 @indent=0,
 @maxwidth=79,
 @newline="\n",
 @output=#<IO:0x8114ee4>,
 @output_width=2>
```

Comment: This would pretty-print the hash to a console, but how do you send `pp` output to a log file?

Answer (score 1):

For more complex objects even with ActiveRecord, this could be achieved with a [`JSON.pretty_generate`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/json#method-i-pretty_generate)

```rb
Rails.logger.debug JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash.as_json)
```